# Why is Robin Hood pronounced the way it is?

Tags: pronunciation

As if it were one word (like "sisterhood"), with only one primary emphasis (ROB-in-hood)? As opposed to, say, "Henry Clay," with two primary stresses (HEN-ry CLAY)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Some dialects minimize the "h" sound (like in French") and might say "Robin'ood", which certainly runs the two together but I don't *generally* find the lack of emphasis you're talking about.

Comment: I certainly stress the name the same way as "Henry Clay".

Comment: It's a tricky question, and I think it largely comes down to a cultural issue.  I've heard it both ways.  In my experience, the run-together, single emphasis style happens more in modern times when referring to the character, as "Robin" and "Hood" are almost always together, and get mentally linked as a single unit identifier, leading to the pronunciation similar to "sisterhood".  Whereas in context, such as in movies about him, it's more the 2 distinct word pronunciation.  I can't back that up without going back and rewatching some movies, but that's how I heard it in my head.

Comment: In Pennsylvania, we say  Accented Unaccented Unaccented rather than Accented Unaccented Accented (ROBinhood rather than ROBin HOOD with the heavier accent on HOOD)

Comment: Because the alternative HENryclay sounds ridiculous.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: You just made my day!  +1.

Comment: @Catija: Well. Some others in this thread apparently do find it.

Comment: @ColinFine: As do I. But I was just watching this silly episode of a silly show from the early '90's, and, guess what.

Comment: @Tofystedeth: The episode I was watching earlier, where they refer to him as Robinhood, is from the early '90's. But you're right, I think, it is a tricky cultural issue.

Comment: @TRomano: Yeah. I wonder why that is.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Robinhood&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRobinhood%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not always pronounced ROBin-hood, for example it can be as expected  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx_4C1cyUZA).

However, the "ROB" part does get emphasised in speech since it can be a play on words

> He's **rob'in** the rich to give to the poor

as pointed out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCEdBJl5Zbo)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. And rob'in the rich is about accent, not tonic stress.

Answer (score 4):

**Tonic Stress in an Intonation Unit.**

The problem of stress in Robin Hood, which is spoken as one word or intonation unit. is this: **If we agree that Robin Hood is said as a single unit, it can only have tonic stress on a single syllable of the unit comprised of three syllables**.

1) Most say: **Rob**in Hood as sisterhood, tonic stress on the first syllable. That takes account of how one would say Robin.

The reason for that I think stems from the single name Robin having the tonic stress on Rob when it stands alone. Therefore, if you add another word with only one syllable (hood), it would tend to be secondary stress and not primary stress.

2) Others **might** say: Robin **Hood**, two equal stresses for Robin, tonic stress on Hood.

However, it also depends on the sentence in which the term appears.

For example:

Q: What's your favorite movie? 
Ans. from a group: Robin Hood! [1) is more likely]

VERSUS

An entire sentence:

Well, they can say what they like about that other movie. I really thought that Robin **Hood** was the best.

The tonic stress could very easily be on the Hood over the arc of that sentence.

If  you take a name like Judy Dench, it has the same stress pattern, if we look at it as a single unit:

**Ju**dy Dench.
I truly doubt anyone would say: Judy **Dench**, with the stress on Dench unless it's in a full sentence where her name becomes emphatic.

"But the best actress was Judy **Dench!**".

So, what takes the tonic stress depends on: What the unit is and whether the unit is a created by two names where the first has two syllables with stress on the first syllable, the second name has one syllable and the two words are said **as a unit**, then, the tonic stress will tend to stay where it is without the second word, unless the unit is spoken in a sentence where emphasis can change drastically.

Just for reference, I'm giving this site, but it could be anyone. I am only posting it because this site likes references.

[intonation unit and tonic stress](http://Tonic%20Stress%20Tonic%20stress%20refers%20to%20the%20syllable%20in%20a%20word%20which%20receives%20the%20most%20stress%20in%20an%20intonation%20unit.%20An%20intonation%20unit%20has%20one%20tonic%20stress.%20It's%20important%20to%20remember%20that%20a%20sentence%20can%20have%20more%20than%20one%20intonation%20unit,%20and%20therefore%20have%20more%20than%20one%20tonic%20stress.)

[Please note: my answer does not deal with the issue of accent, only tonic stress]

Answer (score 2):

I think of this as a cultural issue. Here in UK (where the legend originated) almost everyone says Robin HOOD. This is analogous with Judy DENCH, Peter PAN, etc. To me, ROBin Hood sounds strange and "American" (because I only hear it in US media and when I used to live there).

I think this may be linked to general differences in stress patterns between UK and US. For example, UK says Potato SALad. US says PoTAto Salad.

I am generalising hugely of course. I know there is more than one stress in each phrase - I'm talking about the major one. I also know there is a lot of variation within countries and regions too.

Comment: PoTAto salad, really? First of all, that is too many syllables,If said as a unit, the tonic stress is on SAlad in AmE. And secondly, it would be tomato SAlad as well in AmE The difference in potato would be pronunciation of the TA is potato and not the tonic stress.

Comment: "there is a lot of variation within countries and regions too" And classes as well, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Because historically, his name arose exactly the way you wrote it: as a contraction of 'Rob-in-hood'. Ever noticed how he wears a hooded cloak or hood-like hat in almost every incarnation of the tale? His birth name was Rob (or Robb, or Robert, depending on which source you read), not Robin.

Remember that surnames were unfixed for most of recorded history, and even after they became commonplace, they would usually consist of a person's occupation (Cooper, Smith), location (Hill, Ford), or appearance (Brown, Short). Therefore nicknames were used often to distinguish between people.

Say your name was Edward, and you became renowned for always wearing a cape. You'd start off as Edward-in-cape, and over time, natural attrition through word of mouth would render you Edwin (or Eddin) Cape. Which looks like it would follow the usual name pronunciation format, but actually would still use the contracted stress pattern.

Comment: I don't think the "Rob in Hood" etymology is supported by the evidence. In the early ballads he is "Robyn Hode"  It is only in later texts that "Robyn Hode" is identifed as "Robert, Earl of Huntingdon". In the earliest accounts, his name is "Robyn" and not "Rob".  Perhaps you can provide a source.

Answer (score 0):

Eh?  It's two words. First name = Robin, surname = Hood. It's pronounced with the same stress pattern as any other name, such as Fred Bloggs.

Comment: But I, along with the original poster, *don't* pronounce it with the same stress pattern as *Fred Bloggs.* Fred Bloggs is accented on the syllable *Bloggs,* while Robin Hood is accented on *Rob,* with only a secondary stress on *Hood.*